# Expo Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, runtime-error, react-native-hermes, expo-go

When running an Expo app, you may encounter the error message 'Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes'.

I don't know the reason and I don't know where to fix it.

️Error Image:

[image: 1]

I upgraded the SDK from 46 to 48 (used the command 'expo upgrade')
deleted the node_modules folder, and reinstalled using yarn Install.
 However, when I tried to run it, an error appeared.

I used the command 'npx expo start' to run it.

I want it to be tested live on the Expo Go app.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the final solution, but try to run without development build, instead try to use expo go. That works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).